# How to remove the date pattern from tomcat logs

Tags: tomcat, logging

By default Tomcat appends the date to log files e.g., localhost.2010-12-22.log and same with the catalina log.  I don't want the date in the log file and I can't seem to find how to remove it.  The logging documentation doesn't say anything about the date pattern.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/6669348/354767

Answer (score 31):

None of the other answers helped me much, though Thomas's was closest.  The documentation I found was:

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html

So I added the following to Tomcat's `logging.properties` file. This removes the date from the localhost logs, and the other three log types that Tomcat dates by default:

```
    1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = false
   2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = false
     3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = false
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = false
   #
   # default is true, which causes a date to be added to the filename

    1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.suffix = log
   2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.suffix = log
     3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.suffix = log
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.suffix = log
   #
   # default is .log, but without date, the extra dot is not needed
```

Comment: These properties are also supported by AsyncFileHandler in Tomcat 8.5.

Comment: If the log file does not have an entry in logging.properties it probably is configured using a Valve in the server.xml file. See the answer by SalmanMalik to configure rotation there.

Answer (score 8):

[de_simakov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800802/4320665) was correct for the most part - but it had a one letter typo. Find a configuration similar to this in conf/server.xml

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
      directory="logs"  prefix="http_access" suffix="log"  pattern="common" 
      rotatable="false" resolveHosts="false" />
```

Notice the **rotatable="false"** attribute.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation you link to is for logging within your application, not for logging by the Tomcat server itself. As mentioned in another answer, the appropriate documentation is [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve). On an Ubuntu Server system, you'll want to change the settings in /etc/tomcat7/server.xml. This file may be in another location on your system.

A configuration similar to this will prevent Tomcat from putting the date in the log file name -- but it will also prevent your access log from ever being rotated by Tomcat, which is probably a bad idea unless you set up an appropriate **logrotate** configuration for the server.

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
      directory="logs"  prefix="http_access" suffix="log"  pattern="common" 
      rotateable="false" resolveHosts="false" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be easy on Tomcat 7: [see this docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html)

### renameOnRotate attribute

> By default for a rotatable log the active access log file name will
>   contain the current timestamp in fileDateFormat. During rotation the
>   file is closed and a new file with the next timestamp in the name is
>   created and used. When setting renameOnRotate to true, the timestamp
>   is no longer part of the active log file name. Only during rotation
>   the file is closed and then renamed to include the timestamp. This is
>   similar to the behavior of most log frameworks when doing time based
>   rotation. Default value: false

Comment: On my Tomcat 7.0.64 setting either of `fileDateFormat` or `renameOnRotate` in `logging.properties` file makes no difference, as if those properties are ignored. For example if I add the line `1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.renameOnRotate = true` the log file still has the date in the name.

Comment: @Dialecticus it did not work for me on modifying _logging.properties_, but **did work** on modifying Valve attributes in _server.xml_

Answer (score 2):

The magic property for the default JULI logging in Tomcat is "rotatable".
Usually there are two places where logging is defined in default installations: logging.properties and the server configurations (server.xml).

For the logging.properties you should use this:
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = false

For the server configuration it would look like this:

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory=" prefix="access_log" suffix=".txt" rotatable="false" pattern="%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b" />

Please look here for further details:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve

Answer (score 2):

The more appropriate answer to your direct question is the boolean "renameOnRotate".  The assumption is that you want daily logging, but do not want the timestamp.  This will name the file based on prefix/suffix, and append the timestamp to the log file after the log file has been rotated:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access" suffix=".log" renameOnRotate="true"
           pattern="%a %A %h %H %l %m %t %u %U &quot;%r&quot; %s %b " resolveHosts="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat's logging is governed by the `<Valve>` config elements, usually in `server.xml` or `context.xml`. These allow you to control things like the data suffix.

[Here's the docs for the access log value](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve), which I assume is what you mean by `localhost.2010-12-22.log`. Not sure about `catalina.out`, but that must use a similar mechanism.

Comment: I saw that but this isn't the access log.  The localhost log contains webapp logging (e.g. spring failed to load).  The catalina log contains tomcat errors (e.g. web.xml is malformed).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for a complete example using logrotate.d, remember to replace  with your tomcat version. You have to edit both, server.xml and logging.properties then edit/create a logrotate config. Also, your path to the config files might be different.

logrotate config:

```
vi /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat<version>
```

```
/var/log/tomcat<version>/catalina.out 
{
    daily
    rotate 12
    compress
    copytruncate
    create 640 tomcat adm
}
/var/log/tomcat<version>/*.log
{
    daily
    rotate 12
    compress
    copytruncate
    missingok
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
      if invoke-rc.d tomcat<version> status > /dev/null 2>&1; then \
        invoke-rc.d tomcat<version> restart > /dev/null 2>&1; \
      fi;
    endscript
}
```

server.xml config: I also removed _log. from the prefix so it becomes localhost_access.log

```
vi /var/lib/tomcat<version>/conf/server.xml
```

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
  prefix="localhost_access" suffix=".log" rotatable="false"
  pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

logging.properties config:

```
vi /var/lib/tomcat<version>/conf/logging.properties
```

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.suffix = log
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = false

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.suffix = log
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = false

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.suffix = log
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = false

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.suffix = log
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = false
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers quoting "renameOnRotate" are wrong. This only applies to the access log, not to the "main" logging (which is what the question wants since he's quoted 'localhost' log.

If you need both log rotation and not to have the timestamps (which is generally the case), the bad news is that it is not possible out of the box with tomcat :(

The best solution in that case is to configure it to use log4j globally, which is more flexible and will allow you to be setup in that way.

Comment: localhost log is the access log, i.e. those logs are the webserver logs (tomcat).