# Fast-growing log file under tomcat 8.0

Tags: tomcat, catalina, catalina.out

I have a question regarding tomcat in version 8.0. I have a fast growing catalina.out log file.

Where can I find the setting so that the log only grows to a certain size or maybe I can disable logging into catalina.out at all?

Comment: `catalina.out` can grow from both logging statements and code that calls `System.out`.  Have you looked at both to determine where the excessive logging is originating?  Additionally, what is your operating system?

Comment: For log rotation see the SO question [How to rotate the tomcat localhost log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278614/how-to-rotate-the-tomcat-localhost-log) though it is a fairly old post. And https://dzone.com/articles/how-rotate-tomcat-catalinaout describes how to do size based log rotation on Linux. Are you using Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I **don't recommend disabling logging** into `catalina.out` since you it will not help you in terms of debugging etc.

Therefore, this could be used to clear the log of `catalina.out` file without stopping tomcat with the command below.

```
sudo cat /dev/null > /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/logs/catalina.out
```

To keep `catalina.out` smaller in size, either one of the following ways can be used:

1. You could use the above `Linux` command and add it to a `CronScheduler`
   to run daily/ weekly/ monthly or yearly as preferred.
2. Use `logrotate` tool in `Linux`. It is a log managing command-line tool
   in Linux. This can rotate the log files under different conditions.
   Particularly, **we can rotate log files on a fixed duration or if the
   file has grown to a certain size.** You can click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rotating-logs-logrotate#:%7E:text=logrotate%20is%20a%20log%20managing,manage%20the%20matching%20log%20files.) for more
   info on this.