# Logrotate only for removing old files?

Tags: logrotate

I've a cron will generate daily file with format like data.log.YYYYMMDD and I want to use logrotate only to delete those file older than 5 days.

I tried this but not work. Any idea? Thanks.

/log/data.log.* {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 0
        maxage 5
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logrotate to clean up date stamped files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858752/logrotate-to-clean-up-date-stamped-files)

Answer (score 3):

It's not (easily) feasible... take a look at these posts:

- [logrotate-to-clean-up-date-stamped-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858752/logrotate-to-clean-up-date-stamped-files)
- [logrotate-files-with-date-in-the-file-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962477/logrotate-files-with-date-in-the-file-name/23108631#23108631)

The most easy way to do that is just to make a cron task: [see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858752/logrotate-to-clean-up-date-stamped-files/14860677#14860677), basically something like:

`$ /usr/bin/find /data/tier2/scripts/logs/ -mtime +7 -name "*.log" -print -exec /bin/rm {} \;`